# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of null "
This is the line where i am getting the error:
$(document).append('');
Error is in the line where i am appending the div with id=gridPreviousApps

Note: This exact code without any change has been on the production server for the past 2years. This is the first time, we received this error.

```
 function openDialogPrevApps(titlemessage) {
                $(document).append('<div id="gridPreviousApps"></div>');
                $(document).append('<table id="tblPrevApps"></table>');
                $('#gridPreviousApps').dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    hide: "false",
                    title: titlemessage,
                    width: 800,
                    buttons: {
                        'Ok': function () {
                            //$(this).html('');
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                            //$('#gridPreviousApps').dialog('close');
                            //$(this).closest('.ui-dialog-content').dialog('close'); 
                            //$('.ui-dialog').dialog("close");
                        }
                    }
                });

                $('#gridPreviousApps').dialog("open");

            }
```

Comment: `$(document).append()` should be `$(document.body).append()` since it's not the document where elements are immediately contained.

Comment: You can not append anything to document alone.

Comment: $(document.body) worked. This code was on production for atleast 2 years and never had this issue. Any idea if anything changed on the browser that is causing this issue now?

Comment: Nothing has changed. There's no way this code would have worked.